# Can artifacts be deployed to Pivotal Cloud Foundry from a jenkins server?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, cloud-foundry

I am wondering how I can deploy artifacts to Pivotal Cloud Foundry through a Jenkins pipeline.  I was wondering if I could use something like a artifact-deployer-plugin, or if there is something else that will allow me to do this?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the Cloud Foundry plugin - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cloud+Foundry+Plugin

Other option is write your own shell script. That should be last option.